# Trying to modify file with shell script - with /bin/ex

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ex

I have an xml file I need to modify:

```
...
</web-app>
```

I want to add some text before this line. I've tried with the simple text and it works fine (I used /bin/ex):

```
s/<\/web-app/test &/
```

so I get what I want:

```
...
test </web-app>
```

But the real text I need to insert is:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>400</error-code>
<location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

How should I deal with it? I've tried to create variable, like

```
STR='<error-page>
<error-code>400</error-code>
<location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>'
```

and use it

```
s/<\/web-app/"$STR" &/
```

but result is incorrect. Do I define var incorrectly? Is it possible to have such var with multinelines? How can I insert all these lines before ? Can it be done more simple with sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.  One, your string contains '/' characters, so you should use a different delimiter.  Two, the newlines are problematic.  You could do:

```
 $ STR2=$( echo "$STR" | sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n' )
 $ sed "s@</web-app@$STR2 &@"
```

The assignment to STR2 simply replaces all newlines with `\n`, and works in bash.  In zsh, some word splitting is happening that makes STR2 the same as STR.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
/bin/ex your.xml << EDIT
/<\/web-app>
i
<error-page>
<error-code>400</error-code>
<location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
.
x
EDIT
```

Comment: What for "." is used? exit text input mode?

Answer (score 1):

Crude but effective:

```
sed '/<\/web-app>/i<error-page>\n<error-code>400</errorcode>\n<location>/error.html</location>\n</error-page>' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `STR` contains newlines which `ed` will interpret that as commands. I would suggest putting the content of `STR` into a file and use `r` to read it in. For example:

```
echo -ne '/<\/web-app/-1r OTHER_FILE\nw\n' | ed -s FILE_TO_MODIFY
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
STR='<error-page>\
<error-code>400</error-code>\
<location>/error.html</location>\
</error-page>'
echo -e '...\n</web-app>\n...' | sed '/<\/web-app>/i\'"$STR"
...
<error-page>
<error-code>400</error-code>
<location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
...
```

To edit a file in place:

```
sed -i '/<\/web-app>/i\'"$STR" file
```